# How to dynamically set spring boot port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

so basically I want to run multiple spring boot applications on the same server. This means setting the port number on each of these applications. I was wondering if it could be done using some sort of assigner API? For example before my application starts up it makes a call to some sort of server to get the port it should be running on.

After that I was wondering if I can setup some sort of Spring Cloud Gateway, which can then use this to redirect a url to specific service, again using this server to get the port number?

Answer (score 5):

In `application.properties` file add

```
server.port=1089
```

also, you can configure port programmatically

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setPort(1089);
        });
    }
}
```

Or as a command line parameter:

```
-Dserver.port=1089
```

Comment: You can also pass it as a command line parameter -Dserver.port=18080

Comment: @James i have included your comment in my answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to have a look at doing it the programatical way but instead of hard coding the int I will make an API call but this might work. Will update you.

Answer (score 2):

seek for the file: `application.properties`

file path: /src/main/resources/

add the line:

```
server.port = 8090
```

if you want to achieve random port:

```
server.port = 0
```

Comment: This does not answer my question sorry :( I cannot make a lookup call in the .properties file and I need to know the port so it can't be random

Comment: Do you need to get the port at run time?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to get the port using a API. I managed to do it programmatically.